Runing Redis Stack Server from Python
I downloaded redis-stack-server-7.2.0-v10-x86_64.AppImage and installed redis package (I had to install async-timeout too). Now how can I run the AppImage from my python script and continue the execution of my script to be able to use Redis? I used subprocess module but my script gets stuck when the Redis server starts.
